# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I have been trying to focus element but getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function CustomComponent() {
  const elementRef = useRef;
   useEffect(() => {
    const divElement = elementRef.current;
    divElement.focus();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div ref={elementRef}>
      I'm an element
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please help me how can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be invoking the method `useRef()` instead of just assigning it directly to variable `elementRef`. Try to change your code as follows and see if that helps:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function CustomComponent() {
  const elementRef = useRef();
   useEffect(() => {
    const divElement = elementRef.current;
    divElement.focus();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div ref={elementRef}>
      I'm an element
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes that was sily. Thank you!